# Android Emulator - UnknownHostException . Browser cannot resolve the hostname either

Tags: android

I get the following error when my program attempts to connect to a URL on an Android Emulator:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.xyz.com
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName (InetAddress.java: 513)
```

I then opened a browser on the emulator and typed in the url. It did not work either. However, when I typed in the IP Address into the browser, it worked!

So the issue is that host names is not getting resolved. I have tried restarting the emaulator. Deleting and creating a new AVD (Android Virtual Device) and restarting my computer. I have also checked the AndroidManifest.xml and it does have the following line at the proper place.

```
<uses-permission xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Its been a few months since I used the Android Emulator, but it used to work before. I fail to understand why it is not working anymore and what I can do to make it work. Please advise!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why the host name was not getting resolved. Under Network Conections, the LAN Ethernet Connection (which the system uses) did not have the right DNS servers listed. Once I corrected that, the Android Emulator was able to resolve host names fine! :)

Answer (score 0):

That means your emulator is not connected with net. In-order to connect with the net go to `settings>>>> select wireless and networks >>>>>> uncheck the Airplane Mode` . Now restart your emulator and  `press F8` .The key F8 is used the change the network connection from one mode to another mode. This information may solve your problem.

Comment: The airplane mode was already unchecked. I tried F8 without any success. Thanks for the reply, Balaji!